# Python runs on terminal, not on web browser

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web

I'm trying to run a simple python script on my webserver, but it's not showing up in the web browser.

In terminal I check if python is installed:

```
whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib64/python2.7 /etc/python /usr/local/bin/python3.9-config /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /usr/local/lib/python3.9 /usr/include/python2.7 /opt/imh-python/bin/python2.7 /opt/imh-python/bin/python2.7-config /opt/imh-python/bin/python3.9 /opt/imh-python/bin/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

This tells me that I have python installed. I created a simple file that contains this code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

print('Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n')
print('\r\n')

print('Hello World')
```

I ran `dos2unix` and `chmod a+x` on the file.

I ran the file in terminal and get this output:

```
Content-Type: text/html




Hello World
```

When I try to open the file in the web browser this is the output I get:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

print('Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n')
print('\r\n')

print('Hello World')
```

I changed the single quotes in the print statement to double. I tried different ways of entering new lines, but nothing seems to work. Am I missing or overlooking something crucial here?

Comment: Do you think that just opening a python script in a web browser is how to use Python to dynamically serve up webpages? Because it doesn't work that way at all whatsoever. Python scripts are text files that are interpreted by Python. A browser is just going to display the text in the file. If you want a browser to connect to a Python-based webpage, you have to make Python act as a server. The way you're trying to do it, it seems like you think the browser will just magically execute the Python code and then know what to do with the output.

Comment: Yes, I think I have overlooked something crucial here. My assumption was that if I had the #! /usr/bin/python in the file, it would execute the code.

What is the best way to go about getting python to act as a server.

Comment: @RandomDavis While the question doesn't demonstrate that much research was done prior to asking, don't you think your response is unnecessarily condescending?

Comment: To add a little color - i'm only familiar with client side scripting and php. Luckily (for me) php is easy to write in a .php file, upload to my server, and "execute" on the web browser. My assumption is that if I had python installed, just like php, I could run .py files similarly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The browser doesn't have a Python interpreter. So opening the file in a browser is just going to show your source code. If you want it to show on a browser you need to run it on a server where it can be interpreted. A simple solution is to use Flask, which comes with a development server. Once you've installed flask:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World'


app.run()
```

Then navigate to http://localhost:5000 in your browser.